# URL redirection of webroot folder in cakephp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

I am trying to redirect the URL of webroot folder ie,

**`https://test.example.com/  to  https://www.example.com/test`**

where test => webroot folder.

I have tried redirection in webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /http://test.example.com http://example.com/test
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

also tried the following one :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://test.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/test/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me to solve this..

Comment: Please post your `.htaccess` content

Comment: @JaredChu , I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/test/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```